# Elasticsearch: Scope data in index to itself

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to keep data in a certain index local to itself. I am wondering which elasticsearch setting do I need to apply in order to do so. Specifically, I would like the data in my index to NOT replicate to other nodes.

Rephrase the question: Is there a way to keep data in an index local to itself (for ALL nodes)?

node1 -->  foobar_index ---> {"data" : "asdf"}

node2 -->  foobar_index ---> {"data" : "qwerty"}

node3 -->  foobar_index ---> {"data" : "zxcv"}

Comment: So you want a document stored on one node to not be replicated on another node? If that's right, that's possible to do it, but if one node goes down you will lose data.

Comment: Yes - that is exactly correct. We have some nodes that have information that is appropriate to only itself. Furthermore, we want to be able to prevent replication among nodes that are connected via slow network links. Please let me know which setting --- i've been trying to figure it out all day haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to simply not replicate your indices, i.e. have a shard present on only one node, you can set the number of replicas to 0. Beware, though, that if one of your nodes goes down or gets corrupted, you might lose data.

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/foobar_index/_settings' -d '
{
    "index" : {
        "number_of_replicas" : 0
    }
}'
```

Comment: It didn't work --- I changed the setting and added data and the same data appeared on both nodes.

Comment: Can you update your question with the response you get from: `curl -XGET localhost:9200/_cat/shards` ?

Comment: Ah! I think I see what you mean.... this is what I did: I created the index and then applied that setting. I created data in an index on node1 and did an es.search() on node1 and saw that the data exists. I also did an es.search() on node2 and saw that the data exists...however, the data _doesn't exist on that node_ is what I think is happening. Is that correct?

Comment: By default, the index you have created has 5 primary shards, which are distributed among your three nodes. The document you indexed landed on a specific shard on a specific node, but since there is no replica, the document is only on a single shard, hence on a single node, but you can still retrieve it when querying any node. The way ES works, it hides the shard level details from you.

Comment: Quick question: is there a way to make it inaccessible to the other nodes? Like when you query from a certain node, and the data is not on that node, the query will show up blank.